# How to provide final value for @Query(value=xyz) in spring-boot application

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am reading my SQL queries from property file and the same I am passing to @Query(value=xyz) but getting consistent error "Attribute value must be constant". Is there any solution available for this?

```
public class QueryUtils {

    public static Properties properties;

    static {
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("sql.properties");
            properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(reader);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static  String findAllTags2 = properties.getProperty("ResourceTagRepository.find_all_tags");
}
```

I am trying to use it in blow code.

```
@Component
@Repository
public interface QueryRepo extends JpaRepository<XYZ, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<XYZ> {


    @Query(value = findAllTags2)
    public List<ResourceTagMapping> findAllTags(@Param("list") Set<String> names);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making your String findAllTags2  a final field

Comment: No It is not working. I tried with a sample code as well but not working, Getting the same issue at below @query code ->"Attribute value must be constant"

    @Query(value = RpasQueryUtils.Q1.getval())
    public List<ResourceTagMapping> findAllTags(@Param("list") Set<String> canonicalNames);
public enum RpasQueryUtils {
    Q1("select * from xyz"),

    RpasQueryUtils(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    private final String query;

    public String getValue()
    {
        return query;
    }

    public String getval() {
        return query;
    }
}